# How to generate Captchas on C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, generator, captcha

I have an application which could easily be controlled by a bot over network or even on the local machine(which simuates keyboard and mouse e.g.). 
I want to avoid this using a captcha. The source has to work without internet / has to be generated during runtime on the computer itself.

Is there any open-source project for this or can someone give me a code example or a link ?

Comment: Why should you need to test if a bot is running your application that is not connected to the internet?

Comment: because it´s possibly a bot in internal network (the program runs in an encapsulated intranet with about 3.500 Users)

Comment: try this url https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Captcha-for-Windows-c5ea873c   from here you get sample code for implement captcha in winform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found an article ["Simple CAPTCHA, Create your own in C#"](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99148/Simple-CAPTCHA-Create-your-own-in-C) by Raymund Macaalay. It is for an ASP.NET app, but he generates a normal C# bitmap image using different random fonts in STEP2, so this should also work in your WinForms app.